# [WPF]How to draw a grid on canvas?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

How to draw the following chart as a background on custom canvas inherited from Canvas - system ui element?

Thanks for any useful links.

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can just set `Canvas.Background` to some `DrawingBrush`. This brush can just need to render a Rectangle (by using some `RectangleGeometry`). Because of supporting for `TileMode`, we can repeat this rectangle along both horizontal and vertical axes and make the full grid for you:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
       <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="-10,-10,40,40" 
                                     ViewportUnits="Absolute">
          <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
             <GeometryDrawing>                 
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                   <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,50"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                   <Pen Brush="Gray" Thickness="1"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
             </GeometryDrawing>
          </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
       </DrawingBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
 </Canvas>
```

Note that you can draw something outside the Canvas but its Background is always inside its region. So you need to set the Size for your Canvas correctly.